# Kafka HDFS connector not showing any data

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I got this messages:

```
 WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-test-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2018-07-05 10:58:43,913] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-hdfs-test] Discovered group coordinator broker:19092 (id: 2147482646 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-07-05 10:58:43,919] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-hdfs-test] Revoking previously assigned partitions [] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2018-07-05 10:58:43,920] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-hdfs-test] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-07-05 10:58:46,950] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-hdfs-test] Successfully joined group with generation 9 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-07-05 10:58:46,953] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-hdfs-test] Setting newly assigned partitions [hdfs-test-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2018-07-05 10:58:46,967] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-hdfs-test] Resetting offset for partition hdfs-test-0 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)
[2018-07-05 10:58:46,978] INFO Started recovery for topic partition hdfs-test-0 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter)
[2018-07-05 10:58:47,004] INFO Finished recovery for topic partition hdfs-test-0 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter)
```

but when I want to check that the data is available in HDFS:

I found only this :

> ```
> $ hadoop fs -ls /topics/
> ```

```
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2018-07-05 10:10 /topics/+tmp
```

what shall I do ?? could anyone, help me please ?

Comment: Unclear what your connect properties are doing or if you are producing any data for it to sink to HDFS

Comment: Yes , I produced data to kafka topic , and I added a sink-hdfs using control center of confluent  this what I did to produce data :                                                                       /usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
  --broker-list broker:19092 --topic elk-test \
  --property schema.registry.url=http://kafka-schema-registry:8081 \
  --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}'

Comment: One value will not automatically be sent to HDFS because Connect buffers events in memory. You'll need a more continuous stream

Comment: what shall I do please ?

Comment: Use console producer or Java (or whatever code) to push more data. My point is that Connect doesn't show any errors. I'm not sure what you think is wrong, but it will not send one message at a time, and it is not real-time... Hadoop does not like small files

Comment: Yes finally it works well , I sent many a record of stream  , thanks very much